# Conditional Entropy sum of 2 dice rolls and even/uneven

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

So i have the sum of the 2 dice rolls with X and that the sum is even/uneven with Y out of 0 or 1

Probabilities:
(2=1/36)
(3=2/36)
(4=3/36)
(5=4/36)
(6=5/36)
(7=6/36)
(8=5/36)
(9=4/36)
(1=3/36)
(11=2/36)
(12=1/36)

So my problem is to now determine the conditional entropy H(X|Y) and H(Y|X). I just don't get it how to use the formula.

edit: H(X|Y) = Σ p(yj ) * H(X | Y = yj )
and i don't know how to use Pr [X = xi | Y = yj] cause i don't understand the conditional probability. p[x=2|y=0] = 0/(1/2) right? p[x=2|y=1] = (2/32)/(1/2)=4/32. ?   So the entropy for that is the Sums of all these entropies?

Comment: Which formula did you try to use? What got you stuck in it? Please add your work to the question.

Comment: Got H(X|Y) = 2,3516 and H(Y|X) = 0